# Finding $a+b$ for real $a$ and $b$ such that $f(x)=ax+b$ and $f(bx+a)=x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, contest-math

How do I solve this question on functions?

> There are real numbers $a$ and $b$ for which the function $f$ has the properties that
> $f(x) = ax + b$ for all real numbers $x$, and $f(bx + a) = x$ for all real numbers $x$. What
> is the value of $a + b$?

I was working on this math problem and I couldn't figure it out,
I though that I could say $f(x) = bx + a$, but I quickly realized that was wrong

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: If $f(x)=ax+b$ for all $x$, then what does this require of $f(bx+a)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f(x)=\color{blue}ax+\color{green}b$ for all real number $x$ means that it continues to hold for any real argument of the function $f$ and so $f(\color{red}{bx+a})=\color{blue}a(\color{red}{bx+a})+\color{green}b=abx+a^2+b$ but this last  is required by the problem to be $=x$, so:
$$abx+a^2+b=x\iff \begin{cases}
ab=1\\
a^2+b=0 
\end{cases} \implies \begin{cases}
-a^3=1\\
b=-a^2
\end{cases}\implies a=-1; b=-1
$$

Answer (score 2):

Note that because $f(x)=ax+b$ for all real $x$, we also have
$$
f(bx+a) = a(bx+a) + b = abx + a^2 + b.
$$
It follows that $x = abx + a^2 + b$ for all real $x$.

For $x=0$, we find that $a^2 + b = 0$.

For $x=1$, we find that $1 = ab + a^2 + b = ab$, so $ab = 1$.

From $a^2+b=0$ we have $b=-a^2$, and we obtain $-a^3 = 1$, so $a=-1$. It then follows that $b=-a^2=-1$, so $a+b=-2$.

Answer (score 0):

$bx+a$ is a real number in its own right so $f(bx+a) = a(bx+a) + b = x$, where the first equals sign is the condition $f(x) = ax+b$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$